# next.js dynamic css module import

Tags: next.js, dynamic, import

I have a component and two style files

[image]

there is a json file and a yield based on what style is applied

```
{
    "style_name" : "styles_1"
}
```

```
import data from '@/mocks/data.json'

import styles from `./${data.style_name}.module.css`
```

this didn't work. I also tried dynamic import but it didn't work either.

i am making a portfolio template and preparing different styles for variety.
and I want styles to be managed in one place so I make something like this.
Is it possible to load styles dynamically?